# MySQL REGEXP matching NO exclamation point and then a word

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a problem putting together the right REGEXP in MySQL. I have a database that could have something like this:

```
id | geo
---+--------
1  | NL
2  | US NL
3  | !US
4  | US
```

these are entries for geo-targeting or geo-blocking. #3 is not US, #1 is NL only. If I want to look for everything for the US I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE geo REGEXP '[[:<:]]US[[:>:]]'
```

This would return 2, 3 and 4, but I don't want 3. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE geo REGEXP '^![[:<:]]US[[:>:]]'
```

But that looks for everything starting with an exclamation point. I'm looking for a REGEXP to have the word 'US' and NO exclamation point. I just can't figure out how to make a 'doesn't contain' instead of a 'starts with' since they're both done with '^'

Comment: have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-a-pattern-except-in-three-situations-s1-s2-s3

Comment: Why not use `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` ?

Comment: @Marius.C, it can be done with two REGEXP's as well (SELECT * from DB where geo regexp '[[:<:]]US[[:>:]]' and geo NOT REGEXP "!", but that's not as time-efficient as creating a single regexp, 'contains word, but no exclamation point'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE geo REGEXP '(^|[^!])[[:<:]]US[[:>:]]';
```

This will match any non-word character except `!` before `US`